# Android: Background process for Login

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rest, api

I'm currently working on an Android App which calls HTTPS Requests (like Login, etc.) to a Rest API. My first approach was to use AsyncTask to do this work not on the Main Thread. Unfortunately, I need to know if the Login was successful or not in order to proceed with the code, because if you are not logged in you have only limited access to other parts of the app.

I've tried it with AsyncTask because I used it in a previous project, but I noticed the problem with the return value a little bit to late and now I don't know what technology I should use in order to:

- Don't block the main UI
- Wait for a response
- Evaluate the response with a boolean or something similar

I would appreciate if someone could help me with choosing the best way of accomplishing my problem

Comment: You can try retrofit!! https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Ok and is it prossible with retrofit to create HTTPS Requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for API calls.

But, it will be async as well. That's something you can't avoid.
If you have to wait for call finishes, and process to the app/dashboard, there is no other way.

Practice is to show loader over the screen, send request in async task, wait for response, hide loader, process to the app.

Not sure about your implementation, but other approach could be:

- set as user is not logged in
- process to the app handle user as he isn't logged in yet
- when login request is successful, set some global variable that he's logged in

Comment: Yeah I thought about the same approach, but I have some sort of Auto Login (it checks if the Token is still valid and if so - it will continue without a login)

Comment: You can still use it. If user isn't logged in, set global variable to not logged in and allow him to use app, once he sends login request, handle him as not logged in until you get response from server, and then update global variable.

Comment: So you mean, I should handle my problem with a global variable. And if the user enters a part of the app where he needs permissions I should check the global variable?

Comment: That's common approach for cases as your.
Also, there are two different ways to handle it deeper. 
1. if user isn't logged in, hide all features he can't access
2. show all features, but when he wants to access, check if he is logged in and then open feature or notify him that he must be logged in

Comment: Ok I'll try Retrofit and your this approach of hiding the features and let you know if it works! Thank you in advance!

Comment: My approach was this: I used Retrofit for the API Requests and for notifying other classes (MainActivity) that the Requests finished, I used a Delegater Interface which I implemented in MainActivity and created an instance of the Interface in the Task Class. After the Retrofit Request finished his work, he calls the onResponse() or the onFailure() (depending on its output). I will then call the method of the delegater interface which notifies then the MainActivity! Thanks for helping me, I didn't know that Retrofit works like that!